# What does "even him" refer to?

Tags: barbie-2023

Speaking to Gloria and Sasha, Allan is trying to escape Barbie Land:

> Allan: Not one person would care if Allan was in the Real World.  In
> fact, it's happened before. All of ♪NSYNC, Allan. Yes, **even him**,  so
> come on!

What does "even him" refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Allan says "All of *♪NSYNC*  he is referring to the boy band that he implies escaped from Barbie land

When Allan says "Yes, even him." he refers to a single person from that group that someone would be "surprised" at being an Allan.

So in this instance the person that Allan probably refers to being "Even Him" would be the person that stayed prominent after the bands break up which I interpret to be Justin Timberlake.